# URL Error in Django,Page not found 404

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

This is my `views.py` :

```
from django.http import Http404 
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Album


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'all_albums': all_albums})


def detail(request, album_id):
    try:
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Album does not exist")
    return render(request, '/music/detail.html', {'album': album})
```

This is my `music\urls.py` :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

When I am running this code, I am getting the error as :

[image: error image]

Comment: Which url have you typed in your browser?

Comment: Add project's `urls.py` also.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
This is projects urls

Comment: And what is the page address you are trying to open?

Comment: i want to open songs page

Comment: Write url you are trying to open in browser.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/.Its being opnened but when i want to go http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/ this url i am geting error

Comment: Its been not working.I had id=1 in database.

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As stacktrace said you are trying to open `http://127.0.0.1/music/id/1` page not `http://127.0.0.1/music/1` but there is no such urp pattern in your `urls.py`. You need try to open `http://127.0.0.1/music/1` or add new pattern:

```
url(r'^id/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

to see `http://127.0.0.1/music/id/1` page.